# Loop draggable map like Google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, infinite

I'm building a map with a draggable div containing map-image-pieces and cities on it as a positioned divs. Please if anybody knows how can I make it loop like Google Maps. When I drag "east" of Japan I need to navigate to Hawaii.

I found a couple of "endless vertical scroll" scripts on `jsfiddle`, but all of them are just scrolling to the top and not draggable.

Here is my map: http://worldradiomap.com/map/map and here is an example of how I use it in an iframe: http://worldradiomap.com/map/east-asia

Comment: You know that you can load your own tiles into Google maps?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Woah, how is it possible?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Thank you, Lee, I'll play with it :) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-base

Comment: Also, another example http://maps.marlam.in/?x=70.3&y=-149.82&z=5&m=1&b=17055